# why *ngIf in angular 2 always is executing when use function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I'm trying to create a application with angular 2,and have a auth service in my application , my html template is somthing like this:

```
 <header>
    <div *ngIf="isLogin()"><a href="">profile</a></div>
    <div *ngIf="!isLogin()"><a href="">register</a></div>
    <div *ngIf="!isLogin()"><a href="">signin</a></div>
    </header>

**and this is my class :** 

@Component({
    selector: 'main-menu',
    templateUrl: '/client/tmpl/menu.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class Menu extends Ext {

    public items: any;

    constructor(private _util: UtilService, private _user: UserService) {
        super();


    }

    public isLogin() {

        console.log("test");  <==== my problem is here
        return this._user.authorized();

    }


}
```

always my functions is executing !(in my auth service i have another fuctions that they also runing) !this is for using a function inside *ngif ??!!!
im worry for my resoureces and i want know its a problem or not?

Comment: what you want to do exactly ? obviously your function has to call every time because it is bind with binding on view so every time angular check for any change in the `isLogin`.

Comment: This is like setinterval or a infinite loop!!

Comment: Please can you reformulate your post, it's not really understandable.

Comment: hmm as already said angular will always call the function for binding checking thts y function is being called like infinite loop\

Answer (score 21):

Every time Angulars change detection is run, it evaluates all bindings and therefore calls your functions to check if the view needs updating.

Using functions in bindings is discouraged. Either assign the value to a property of your component class and bind to this property instead, or use observables and the `| async` pipe to notify Angular about changed values.

Another option is to use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` where Angular change detection is only run when an input value has changed.

Comment: @AlirezaValizade, see Günter's other answer about that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37024918/angular2-changedetection-or-observable/37025051#37025051

Comment: I've used functions for ngIf in many places in my project. Is there any risk of pages crashing due to them? Should I change them or is it fine?

Comment: If they don't do any actual work, just returning a simple value, they aren't too bad. Change detection with bare fields is still more efficient. If you use `OnPush`, it's even less an issue, because change detection doesn't run that frequently. If the function does even moderately expensive calculation, definitely change it into a property binding.

Comment: What about using getters? Would it be any better then notmal functions?

Comment: A getter is just syntactic sugar and otherwise the same as a function.

Comment: What if the ngIf login is in the template? Is it better then using a function?

Comment: @UdiMazor not sure what you mean.  isLogin is in the template in the question.