# Why angular2 executes methods several times?

Tags: angular, lifecycle

my application structure looks like this:

[image]

**ts:**

```
...
export class TodoListComponent {

    get sortedTodos():ITodo[] {
            console.log(this.counter++);
            ...
        } 
    ....
```

**html:**

```
  <div class="todo-item" *ngFor="let todo of sortedTodos" [class.completed]="todo.completed">
        <todo-list-item [todo]="todo" class="todo-item" (deleted)="onTodoDeleted(todo)"
                        (toggled)="onTodoUpdated($event)"></todo-list-item>
    </div>
```

If I start application I see in console:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

I really confusing about this behaviour. for me it looks very strange and I think it can lead to bugs and performance issues. Please explain why it executes **6!** times when I load page at once.

I am not sure that I provided all needed information in topic. Feel free to request womething else. Also all code base can be found [bitbucket repo link](https://bitbucket.org/gredwhite/angular2-demo/src)

**P.S.**

full ts file content:

```
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from "@angular/core"

import {ITodo} from "../../shared/todo.model";
import {TodoService} from "../../shared/todoService";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "todo-list",
    templateUrl: "todo-list.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["todo-list.component.css"],
})
export class TodoListComponent {
    @Input() todos:ITodo[];

    @Output() updated:EventEmitter<ITodo> = new EventEmitter<ITodo>();
    @Output() deleted:EventEmitter<ITodo> = new EventEmitter<ITodo>();

    get sortedTodos():ITodo[] {
        return !this.todos ? [] :
            this.todos.map((todo:ITodo)=>todo)
                .sort((a:ITodo, b:ITodo)=> {
                    if (a.title > b.title) {
                        return 1;
                    } else if (a.title < b.title) {
                        return -1;
                    }
                    return 0;
                })
                .sort((a:ITodo, b:ITodo)=> (+a.completed - (+b.completed)));
    }

    onTodoDeleted(todo:ITodo):void {
        this.deleted.emit(todo);
    }

    onTodoUpdated(todo:ITodo):void {
        this.updated.emit(todo);
    }

    constructor(private todoService:TodoService) {
    }
}
```

Comment: How many elemnts are there in the ITodo[] array returned by getSortedTodos? If the answer is 6 you can assume that it calls the getter for each elemnt. (note: you bitbucket link does not work)

Comment: @StephaneM 5  Sorrry for bad link. I corrected the post. Actually count of elements equally 4.

Answer (score 5):

It executes 6 times because:

There is a `tick` method in `ApplicationRef` class and it is **executed 3 times by 2 change detection cycles**. If you will enable production mode by calling `enableProdMode()` it will be executed 3 times

`ApplicationRef` is an reference to an Angular application running on a page. The `tick` method is running change detection from the root to leaves.

Here is how `tick` method looks (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.3.0/modules/%40angular/core/src/application_ref.ts#L493-L509):

```
tick(): void {
  if (this._runningTick) {
    throw new Error('ApplicationRef.tick is called recursively');
  }

  const scope = ApplicationRef_._tickScope();
  try {
    this._runningTick = true;
    this._views.forEach((view) => view.ref.detectChanges()); // check
    if (this._enforceNoNewChanges) {
      this._views.forEach((view) => view.ref.checkNoChanges()); // check only for debug mode
    }
  } finally {
      this._runningTick = false;
      wtfLeave(scope);
  }
}
```

For **debug mode** `tick` starts **two change detection cycles**. So `detectChangesInternal` within compiled view will be called twice.

[image]

And as your `sortedTodos` property is a getter so it will be executed everytime as a function.

Read more about it here ([Change Detection in Angular 2](https://vsavkin.com/change-detection-in-angular-2-4f216b855d4c#.mb32t749o))

So then we know that our `sortedTodos` getter is called twice for one `tick`

**Why is the `tick` method executed 3 times?**

**1)** First `tick` is running manually by bootstrapping application.

```
private _loadComponent(componentRef: ComponentRef<any>): void {
  this.attachView(componentRef.hostView);
  this.tick();
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.3.0/modules/%40angular/core/src/application_ref.ts#L479

**2)** Angular2 is running within zonejs so it's the main thing which manages change detection. Mentioned above `ApplicationRef` is subscribed to `zone.onMicrotaskEmpty`.

```
this._zone.onMicrotaskEmpty.subscribe(
  {next: () => { this._zone.run(() => { this.tick(); }); }});
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.3.0/modules/%40angular/core/src/application_ref.ts#L433

**onMicrotaskEmpty** event is an indicator when **zone** **gets stable**

```
private checkStable() {
  if (this._nesting == 0 && !this._hasPendingMicrotasks && !this._isStable) {
    try {
      this._nesting++;
      this._onMicrotaskEmpty.emit(null); // notice this
    } finally {
      this._nesting--;
      if (!this._hasPendingMicrotasks) {
        try {
          this.runOutsideAngular(() => this._onStable.emit(null));
        } finally {
          this._isStable = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.3.0/modules/%40angular/core/src/zone/ng_zone.ts#L195-L211

So after some zonejs task this event is emitted

**3)** You're using `angular2-in-memory-web-api` package and when you're trying to get mock data it does following:

```
createConnection(req: Request): Connection {
    let res = this.handleRequest(req);

    let response = new Observable<Response>((responseObserver: Observer<Response>) => {
      if (isSuccess(res.status)) {
        responseObserver.next(res);
        responseObserver.complete();
      } else {
        responseObserver.error(res);
      }
      return () => { }; // unsubscribe function
    });

    response = response.delay(this.config.delay || 500); // notice this
    return {
      readyState: ReadyState.Done,
      request: req,
      response
    };
}
```

https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/blob/0.0.20/src/in-memory-backend.service.ts#L136-L155

It start regular zonejs task cycle which makes zone `unStable` and finally after task execution is emitted described above `onMicrotaskEmpty` event again

You can find more details about zonejs here

- http://blog.kwintenp.com/how-the-hell-do-zones-really-work/
- http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html

**Recap**:

So as you can see your solution a bit wrong. You shouldn't use getter or function as binding within your template. Possible solution you can find here

- [why *ngIf in angular 2 always is executing when use function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37238310/why-ngif-in-angular-2-always-is-executing-when-use-function/37240591#37240591)

Answer (score 1):

This is how [Template expressions](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#template-expressions) works in Angular 2, Angular executes template expressions more often than we think.They can be called after every keypress or mouse move.

There are **[Expression guidelines](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#no-visible-side-effects)** so that there is no bugs or performance issues.

> Template expressions can make or break an application. Please follow
>   these guidelines:
>
> The
>   only exceptions to these guidelines should be in specific
>   circumstances that you thoroughly understand.
>
> **NO VISIBLE SIDE EFFECTS**
>
> A template expression should not change any application state other
>   than the value of the target property.
>
> This rule is essential to Angular's "unidirectional data flow" policy.
>   We should never worry that reading a component value might change some
>   other displayed value. The view should be stable throughout a single
>   rendering pass.
>
> **QUICK EXECUTION**
>
> Angular executes template expressions more often than we think. They
>   can be called after every keypress or mouse move. Expressions should
>   finish quickly or the user experience may drag, especially on slower
>   devices. Consider caching values computed from other values when the
>   computation is expensive.
>
> **SIMPLICITY**
>
> Although it's possible to write quite complex template expressions, we
>   really shouldn't.
>
> A property name or method call should be the norm. An occasional
>   Boolean negation (!) is OK. Otherwise, confine application and
>   business logic to the component itself, where it will be easier to
>   develop and test.
>
> **IDEMPOTENCE**
>
> An idempotent expression is ideal because it is free of side effects
>   and improves Angular's change detection performance.
>
> In Angular terms, an idempotent expression always returns exactly the
>   same thing until one of its dependent values changes.
>
> Dependent values should not change during a single turn of the event
>   loop. If an idempotent expression returns a string or a number, it
>   returns the same string or number when called twice in a row. If the
>   expression returns an object (including an Array), it returns the same
>   object reference when called twice in a row.

Number **6** in your case depends upon how many expression you have in your HTML template.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

> The NgFor directive instantiates a template once per item from an iterable. The context for each instantiated template inherits from the outer context with the given loop variable set to the current item from the iterable.

I would assume you have 6 items in your `ITodo[]` returned by `getSortedTodos()`, and for each loop in `*ngFor="let todo of sortedTodos"`,  `get` in `TodoListComponent` is called once, which is why you see six numbers been printed.

Source:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html

Comment: I tried to remove all 4 items from mock database but anyway I see 6 calls although I removed items don't swhown on the screen.

Comment: You need to provide more information. What other code are there in `get sortedTodos():ITodo[] `? What do you see in rendered HTML page? What is the `sortedTodos` in `*ngFor="let todo of sortedTodos"`?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/gredwhite/angular2-demo/src/0677353ac934ab886971236c3eba137adac053cf/app/components/todos/todo-list/todo-list.component.ts?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it wrong ..

```
*ngFor="let todo of sortedTodos"
```

this is not intelligent code. If one todo changes then it will re-render the entire list.

You need to use trackBy. This introduces intelligence. When using trackBy Angular2 only updates the list items that change.

This should reduce the number of times the code is executed.