# using a function in *ngIf runs several times instead of once

Tags: angular

## Template

```
<pre *ngIf="isAdmin()">{{email|json}} - {{user|json}}</pre>
```

## Component

```
isAdmin() {
    console.log('isAdmin: ', this.bcAuthService.isAdmin());
    return this.bcAuthService.isAdmin();
}
```

## Service

```
isAdmin() {
    return this.admins.includes(localStorage.getItem("email"));
}
```

## Problem

the function in the component keeps printing several times. Why? Is this wrong? What is a better way?

[image]

Comment: Template methods will almost always be called multiple times. The same is true for `*ngFor` that it is iterated over multiple times. If you have something that executes an expensive call then you should cache the result and return that either in the method or use ngOnInit to retrieve/calculate the values and set them in your component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after finding this [why *ngIf in angular 2 always is executing when use function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37238310/why-ngif-in-angular-2-always-is-executing-when-use-function)

i resolved the problem by

### component

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.is_admin();
}
is_admin() {
    this.isAdmin = this.bcAuthService.isAdmin();
}
```

### html

```
<pre *ngIf="isAdmin">{{email|json}} - {{user|json}}</pre>
```

Answer (score 8):

Template methods will almost always be called multiple times. The same is true for `*ngFor` that it is iterated over multiple times. If you have something that executes an expensive call then you should cache the result and return that either in the method or use ngOnInit to retrieve/calculate the values and set them in your component.

## Template code

```
<pre *ngIf="isAdmin">{{email|json}} - {{user|json}}</pre>
```

## Component

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    isAdmin: boolean;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.isAdmin = this.bcAuthService.isAdmin();
        console.log('isAdmin: ', this.isAdmin);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did the same what you recommended me.

Answer (score 0):

Now you don't have method(member instead) and it's not spamming "isAdmin: true" but it's not means that problem is resolved.

You can be interested in `changeDetection` of the component and [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)
to actually tell angular when `isAdmin` is changed to update template(detectChanges).